# Characterization of the determinant.

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I'm trying to understand the characterization of the determinant given to me by my professor.

Given a vector space $V$ over $F$ we then defined $Alt^k(V)$ to be the vector space consisting of all alternating and $k$-multilinear forms from $V^k$ into $F$. He claimed that there is an association $V \leadsto Alt^k(V)$ which is functorial, specifically a cofunctor. I don't think the category theory terms were germane to the discussion, but the fact that given $T: V \rightarrow V$, we can induce a map $\widetilde{T}:Alt^k(V) \rightarrow Alt^k(V)$ seems to be the key.

We went on to show that if $\dim(V) =n$, that $Alt^n(V)$ is one dimensional, and therefore given $T:V \rightarrow V$, the induced map from $Alt^n(V) \rightarrow Alt^n(V)$  has to be simply multiplication by a scalar. This lead us to our definition,

The determinant of $T$ is the **unique** scalar such that $\tilde{T}: Alt^n(V) \rightarrow Alt^n(V)$ is defined by multiplication by $\det(T)$. This last bit seems circular to me? Why should it be that the scalar is unique? I know the terms are specific, if there's any expansion I could do please let me know, I would greatly appreciate any insight that can be provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify your first point, it's useful to write out exactly how the functor acts: it takes a vector space $V$ to $\mathrm{Alt}^k(V)$, and a map $T\colon V \to W$ to the map $T^*\colon \mathrm{Alt}^k (W) \to \mathrm{Alt}^k(V)$ where the latter map is defined by $T^*(f)(v_1,\ldots,v_k) =f(Tv_1,\ldots,Tv_k)$.

Now onto your question regarding uniqueness. It is indeed true that if $V$ is $n$-dimensional, then $\mathrm{Alt}^k(V)$ is $\binom{n}{k}$ dimensional (prove this!), so for $k=n$, it's one dimensional. *Any* linear map from a one dimensional space to itself must act by multiplying by a scalar, i.e. in our case $T^* f= \lambda f$ for some scalar $\lambda$ which doesn't depend on $f$. The easiest way to see this is to choose a basis (i.e. one multilinear form $e$ which spans the whole space) for $\mathrm{Alt}^k(V)$. Then for any scalar $a\in F$, we have $T^*(ae) = aT^*(e) = \lambda(ae).$

This scalar $\lambda$ which $T^*$ acts by is what we define the determinant to be. It's then a good exercise to show that this definition of the determinant is equivalent to the various other ones given throughout linear algebra.

Comment: Do you have any hints for showing that $\mathrm{Alt}^k(V)$ has dimension $\binom{n}{k}$? I was thinking maybe the dual space of $\mathrm{Alt}^k(V)$ would be a place to start? I guess then $\hom(\mathrm{Alt}^k(V), F)$ are maps from $\mathrm{Alt}^k(V) \rightarrow F \rightarrow F$, then is there some argument to show that we need to specify $\binom{n}{k}$ vectors to form a basis of the dual?

Comment: @AndreyYanyuk show that any $f \in \mathrm{Alt}^k(V)$ is be uniquely determined by its values on a $k$-tuple of basis vectors of $V$ listed in increasing order.

Comment: I couldn't find a way to fit the proof in a comment, but what do you think of my attempt? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4414108/showing-that-textrmaltkv-has-dimension-binomnk