# Showing that $\textrm{Alt}^k(V)$ has dimension $\binom{n}{k}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Given a vector space $V$ over $F$ define $\textrm{Alt}^k(V)$ to be the vector space of all alternating multilinear forms from $V^k \rightarrow F$. I tried to show that this vector space has dimension $\binom{n}{k}$ but I'm not sure about work, particularly if I'm relying on too much English. Any ways to improve or correct the proof if there are errors would be greatly appreciated.

Let $\{e_1,...,e_n\}$ be a basis for $V$, $B \in \textrm{Alt}^k(V)$ and let $\{v_1,...,v_k\}$ be an arbitrary collection of vectors in $V$. We can express each vector as a linear combination of the basis vectors, so
\begin{align*}
 v_1 & = a_{11}e_1+...+a_{1n}e_n \\
 \vdots & \\
 v_k & = a_{k1}e_1+...+a_{kn}e_n.
\end{align*}
Then if we evaluate our alternating multilinear form at these $k$ vectors we get
\begin{align*}
B(v_1,...,v_k) &= B(a_{11}e_1+...+a_{1n}e_n,...,a_{k1}e_1+...+a_{kn}e_n).
\end{align*}
Expanding by multilinearity in the first argument gives that
$$
B(v_1,...,v_k) = \sum_{i_1 =1}^nB(a_{i_11}e_{i_1},a_{21}e_1+...+a_{2n}e_n,...,a_{k1}e_1+...+a_{kn}e_n).
$$
If you proceed exactly in the same way for the remaining arguments we get
$$
B(v_1,...,v_k) = \sum_{i_1 =1}^n \sum_{i_2 =1}^n ... \sum_{i_k =1}^n B(a_{i_11}e_{i_1},...,a_{i_kn}e_{i_k}).
$$
Next we can use the multilinearity of scalar multiplication to get that
$$
B(v_1,...,v_k) = \sum_{i_1 =1}^n \sum_{i_2 =1}^n ... \sum_{i_k =1}^na_{i_11}...a_{i_kn}B(e_{i_1},...,e_{i_k}).
$$
Next we want to use the fact that $B$ is alternating to simplify this expression further; because we know that whenever $B$ has repeated arguments it evaluates to zero, we can eliminate the summands which have any two of the $i_1,i_2,...,i_k$ equal. This corresponds to summing over permutations of the $i_1,...,i_k$ indices, i.e
$$
B(v_1,...,v_k) = \sum_{(i_1,...,i_k) \in S_k}^n a_{i_11}...a_{i_kn}B(e_{i_1},...,e_{i_k}).
$$
where $S_k$ is the permutation group on $k$ letters. Because $B$ has $k$ arguments and there are $n$ basis vectors for $V$, the summands now correspond to how many different ways we can construct arguments for $B$ by picking $k$ unordered basis vectors from the total list of $n$, but this is exactly $\binom{n}{k}$.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $$B(v_1,...,v_k) = \sum_{i_1 =1}^nB(a_{1 i_1}e_{i_1},a_{21}e_1+...+a_{2n}e_n,...,a_{k1}e_1+...+a_{kn}e_n).$$ Anyway, I would suggest trying to find a candidate basis for $\text{Alt}^k(V)$ using computations similar to what you have written, and then prove that it is a basis. Also your last formula is wrong; $S_k$ is the set of permutations of $\{1, \dots, k\}$, while $i_1, \dots. i_n \in \{1, \dots, n\}$.